# Integrate $1/\sqrt{9-16x^2}$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I need to compute
$$
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{9-16x^2}}
$$
using this table of integrals formula:
[Table of Integrals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGW9R.png)

I am getting $\arcsin(x/3) + k$ but I know that is wrong. What do I need to do to correctly solve this problem

Comment: Maybe you could start by telling us *how* you got to this result?

Comment: $16x^2$ = $(4x)^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

$$x = \frac{3}{4}\sin\theta ~~~~~ \text{d}x = \frac{3}{4}\cos\theta\ \text{d}\theta$$

Hence you obtain:

$$\int \frac{\frac{3}{4}\cos\theta\ \text{d}\theta}{\sqrt{9(1 - \sin^2\theta)}} = \int \frac{\frac{3}{4}\cos\theta\ \text{d}\theta}{\sqrt{9\cos^2\theta}} = \int \frac{\frac{3}{4}\cos\theta\ \text{d}\theta}{3\cos\theta} = \frac{1}{4}\int\text{d}\theta = \frac{\theta}{4}$$

Substituting back to $x$, using the substitution we made at the beginning, you have $\theta = \arcsin\left(\frac{4x}{3}\right)$ hence the result is

$$\frac{1}{4}\arcsin\left(\frac{4x}{3}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

hint: 
$$x=\frac{3}{4}\sin u$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that
$$
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{9-16x^2}}
 = \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{3^2-(4x)^2}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{9-16x^2} = \sqrt{16\left(\frac9{16}-x^2\right)} = 4\sqrt{\frac9{16}-x^2} = 4\sqrt{\left(\frac34\right)^2 - x^2}$$  Now use the table and be careful with handling that factor of $4$ outside of the radical.

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$
9-16x^2=9\left(1-\left(\frac{4x}{3}\right)^2\right)
$$
Now set $t=4x/3$, so $dx=\frac{3}{4}\,dt$ and the integral is
$$
\frac{3}{4}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt
$$
which is elementary.